# PHP SOAP call connection reset

Tags: php, soap

I got the following cod trying to connect to a SOAP server and running a command. However as soon as I use $client->login(**array()**) chrome retuns with a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

When I do it without the array() like:

```
$client->actief($params);
```

I get the message "NOT FOUND" back from the SOAP client.
Can anybody point me in the right direction...

Wheb I connect to the soapClient and use the function __getFunctions() I get back the functions:

> array(3) { [0]=> string(41) "actiefResponse actief(actief $parameters)" [1]=> string(38) "loginResponse login(login $parameters)" [2]=> string(41) "logoutResponse logout(logout $parameters)" }

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient(
    'https://xxxx',
    array(
        'trace' => 1,
        'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
        'location' => 'https://xxx',
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create(
            array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer'       => false,
                    'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
$params = new SoapVar('
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <S2:actief
          xmlns:S2="urn:sessie:sessie"
          xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <S2:dsClientContext>
            <ttClientContextValue>
               <contextClass>global</contextClass>
               <contextName>guid</contextName>
               <contextType>character</contextType>
               <valueCharacter>a35702d5-6dc1-2e8d-11e8-01d65f768678</valueCharacter>
               <valueNumber>0.0</valueNumber>
               <valueDate xsi:nil="true" />
               <valueClob xsi:nil="true" />
               <valueBlob xsi:nil="true" />
            </ttClientContextValue>
         </S2:dsClientContext>
      </S2:actief>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
', XSD_ANYXML);

try {
$result = $client->actief(array('parameters' => $params));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Somehow when I don't use WSDL mode and specify the 'uri' option it works well and I get a response from SOAP.

I really don't know why it doesn't work in WSDL mode and it works in non-wdsl mode.